# Handling data skewness in RandomForest : spark ML

Tags: scala, apache-spark, random-forest

What is the best way to handle data skewness in spark' RandomForest implementation (ml, not mllib) ? Isn't there any in-house support in spark for the same? (apart from over-sampling and sub-sampling). Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Random Forests are considered to be insensitive to data skewness.  There are extremes of course.  Why are you suggesting you have a problem?

Comment: Yeah.. i am doing binary classification with classes in the ratio 95:5 (A:B) . Post the training, the model is unable to classify the expected samples as B.(Recall is pretty poor, with ~ 0.5%).

Comment: Also, when i try to under sample the class A, so as to adjust the skewness in the ratio (60:40), i see a pretty significant jump in the recall (close to 50%), but precision takes a hit (drops down to 10% from the original 60%)